# Moving service configuration from the config to code

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following configuration in my app.config:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
      <httpTransport/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="/../" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="myContract" name="myName"/>
</client>
```

Using this configuration the service works as expected.

For several reasons i can't use the app.config file in the production environment, so i want to define the bindings in c# instead. I did the following:

```
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var address = new EndpointAddress(url);

        binding.Security = new BasicHttpSecurity() { Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport };
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        var client = new MyClient(binding, address);
```

This works for the first part, but then fails on using an incorrect message version. I can see this is defined in the custombinding, but i'm not sure how to translate this binding to my code. I did try quite a lot, but with no result so far.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you improve your question? I didn't understand. You want to keep using the config file and use it in the code?

Comment: Updated my question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also add the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to leverage the [`ConfigurationChannelFactory<TChannel>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/configuration-channel-factory) class to configure your client using XML configuration from a source other than an app.config file (e.g. an XML string read from a database, from a resource in your executable, or from some other custom source).

The XML format is IMHO easier to read and maintain than a configuration built using code.

To do this, the steps are as follows:

- Get a string with your XML configuration data, e.g.:

  ```
  string configurationData = @"<configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
      ...
      ";
  ```
- Save it to a temporary file:

  ```
  var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
  File.WriteAllText(tempFileName, configurationData);
  ```
- Generate a `System.Configuration.Configuration` object from the temp file:

  ```
  var filemap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
  {
      ExeConfigFilename = tempFileName
  };
  var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(filemap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
  ```
- Create a `ChannelFactory<TChannel>` from the configuration:

  ```
  var channelFactory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<TChannel>(endpointConfigurationName, config, remoteAddress);
  ```
- Once you've created your `ChannelFactory<TChannel>`, you can delete the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `BasicHttpBinding` instead of `CustomBinding`

you should do something like this:

```
var binding = new CustomBinding();
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
{
    MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None),
    WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max
};
binding.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
```

But, if you are using .net core you might have issues with this, because there is an open issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2711

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using wshttpbinding. 
You could try the code below.Please change to your address and contract.

```
  WSHttpBinding wsbinding = new WSHttpBinding();
        wsbinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        wsbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        wsbinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
        wsbinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        wsbinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
        wsbinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        using (ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService> channelFacoty = new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>(wsbinding, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost")))
        {
            ICalculatorService cal = channelFacoty.CreateChannel();
           Console.WriteLine( cal.Add(1, 3));
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the WebHttBinding:

```
binding = new WebHttpBinding
{
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
    MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
    ReaderQuotas =
        {
            MaxDepth = 2147483647,
            MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
            MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
            MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647,
            MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647
        },
    Security = new WebHttpSecurity()
    {
        Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
        Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
        {
            ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm
        }
    }
};
```